# I'm unable to insert data into my SQLiteDatabase

Tags: android, sqlite

**I'm creating a SQLiteDatabase in Android Studio that loads and calculates the food calories and I'm getting the error below after I press submit (The app then crashes):**

2020-02-06 21:36:47.840 26379-26379/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) table food_tbl has no column named calories
2020-02-06 21:36:47.840 26379-26379/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting name=beer calories=567 recorddate=1581043007840
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table food_tbl has no column named calories (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO food_tbl(name,calories,recorddate) VALUES (?,?,?)

****Here is my DatabaseHandler code:****

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
private final ArrayList<Food> foodList = new ArrayList<>();


public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, Constants.DATABASE_NAME, null, Constants.DATABASE_VERSION);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // create table
    String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + Constants.TABLE_NAME + "("
            + Constants.KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + Constants.FOOD_NAME +
            " TEXT, " + Constants.FOOD_CALORIES_NAME + " INT, " + Constants.DATE_NAME + " LONG);";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Constants.TABLE_NAME);


    // create a new one
    onCreate(db);

}

// Get total items saved
public int getTotalItems() {
    int totalItems = 0;

    String query = " SELECT * FROM " + Constants.TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase dba = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = dba.rawQuery(query, null);

    totalItems = cursor.getCount();

    cursor.close();

    return totalItems;
}

//get total calories consumed
public int totalCalories(){
    int cals = 0;

    SQLiteDatabase dba = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String query = "SELECT SUM( " + Constants.FOOD_CALORIES_NAME + " ) " +
            "FROM " + Constants.TABLE_NAME;

    Cursor cursor = dba.rawQuery(query, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        cals = cursor.getInt(0);
    }

    cursor.close();
    dba.close();


    return cals;
}

//delete food item
public void deleteFood(int id) {

    SQLiteDatabase dba = this.getWritableDatabase();
    dba.delete(Constants.TABLE_NAME, Constants.KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[]{ String.valueOf(id)});

    dba.close();
}

//add content to db - add food
public void addFood(Food food) {

    SQLiteDatabase dba = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Constants.FOOD_NAME, food.getFoodName());
    values.put(Constants.FOOD_CALORIES_NAME, food.getCalories());
    values.put(Constants.DATE_NAME, System.currentTimeMillis());

    dba.insert(Constants.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

    Log.v("Added Food item", "Yesss!!");

    dba.close();
}

// Get all foods
public ArrayList<Food> getFoods() {

    foodList.clear();

    SQLiteDatabase dba = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = dba.query(Constants.TABLE_NAME,
            new String[]{Constants.KEY_ID, Constants.FOOD_NAME, Constants.FOOD_CALORIES_NAME,
            Constants.DATE_NAME}, null, null, null, null, Constants.DATE_NAME + " DESC ");

    // loop through...
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            Food food = new Food();
            food.setFoodName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.FOOD_NAME)));
            food.setCalories(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.FOOD_CALORIES_NAME)));
            food.setFoodId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_ID)));

            DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
            String date = dateFormat.format(new Date(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.DATE_NAME))).getTime());

            food.setRecordDate(date);

            foodList.add(food);

        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();
    dba.close();

    return foodList;
}
```

}

Comment: onUpgrade isn't called maybe.

Comment: use Room, it's very easy and clean

Comment: You likely had a previous version of this code with a different column name but didn't change the database version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + Constants.TABLE_NAME + "("
            + Constants.KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + Constants.FOOD_NAME +
            " TEXT, " + Constants.FOOD_CALORIES_NAME + " INT, " + Constants.DATE_NAME + " LONG"+ ")";
```

Comment: No, that didn't work. I thought that would for sure.

Answer (score 0):

As per the crash log I can understand you need to add the column `calories` in your table  `food_tbl`.

please add `calories` column to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think your create table query is wrong so try this below code.

```
String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + Constants.TABLE_NAME + "("
        + Constants.KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + Constants.FOOD_NAME +
        " TEXT," + Constants.FOOD_CALORIES_NAME + " INTEGER," + Constants.DATE_NAME + " DATETIME);"
```

Comment: That didn't do it either

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `totalCalories()` in the `cursor.getInt(0)`
You are retrieving nothing from the database, since you have an integer column in the 1st index but your retrieving it from the 0th index.
Solution:

```
cursor.getInt(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem: there was a compatibility issue with the emulator in android studio I was using. I was using Nexus 5 API 24 and apparently that is not compatible with sqlite3. I switched to Pixel 3 API 26 for my emulator and it worked. Thanks for all of your responses. It helped.